# How to create spark-sql database from jdbc connection

Tags: apache-spark

I'm using spark-sql, I want to create queries to join different tables from database.

Apache spark and connection is already working
Example:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW jdbcTable
USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
OPTIONS (
  url "jdbc:mysql://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/mydatabase",
  driver "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver",
  dbtable "mydatabase.mytable1",
  user "XXXX",
  password "xxx"
);
spark-sql> SELECT * FROM jdbcTable;
1       my_data
Time taken: 3.91 seconds, Fetched 1 row(s)
```

What I need is is something like USE or CREATE mydatabase USING the jdbc connection to be able to run queries with join tables.

Based of the [Spark SQL Syntax](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax.html), I tried the following options:

```
spark-sql> USE DATABASE mydatabase
         > USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
         > OPTIONS (
         >   url "jdbc:mysql://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/mydatabase",
         >   driver "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver",
         >   user "XXXX",
         >   password "xxx"
         > );
Error in query:
mismatched input 'mydatabase' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 1, pos 13)


spark-sql> CREATE DATABASE mydatabase
         > USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
         > OPTIONS (
         >   url "jdbc:mysql://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/mydatabase",
         >   driver "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver",
         >   user "XXXX",
         >   password "xxx"
         > );
Error in query:
mismatched input 'USING' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 2, pos 0)
```

Is there a way to USE or CREATE a database from a jdbc connection in spark-sql command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **no**. Refer to spark official documentation:

> The Spark SQL CLI is a convenient tool to **run the Hive metastore**
> **service in local mode and execute queries** input from the command line.

It cannot directly connect to external mysql service using JDBC.